# Clustering data after reducing dimension with autoencoder

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, autoencoder, dimensionality-reduction, text-database

My goal is to identify clusters in my dataset that containe around 10 categoricals and/or numericals columns and 3 textual description columns.
After a few researchs, i thought about a **3 steps process**:

- **pre-processing my data** (normalize my 10 columns and doing tf-idf on the text data - shape is something like (89,000, 41206) )
  After a few treatment, i use a Column Transformer as follow :

```py
    column_trans = ColumnTransformer([
                                      ('scale', StandardScaler(), make_column_selector(dtype_include=np.number)),
                                      ('res_vec', TfidfVectorizer(), "Résumé de l'incident"),
                                    ('desc_vec', TfidfVectorizer(), "Description de l'incident")],remainder='drop')
    
    #On applique l'objet de transformation à note dataframe
    all_features = column_trans.fit_transform(df_incidents_sample)
```

(I also tried to use PCA:

```
#First, data normalization 
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X)
X_scaled = scaler.transform(X)

from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

pca = PCA(.70)
pca.fit(X_scaled)
principalComponents = pca.components_
print("Percentage of variance explained: ")
print(pca.explained_variance_ratio_)
print("Main components:")
print(principalComponents)
```

```
Percentage of variance explained:  
[0.18618277 0.17050933 0.10841001 0.09733908 0.09186758 0.08251782] 

Main components:
[[ 0.14725228  0.37825793  0.36558713  0.11637642 -0.22776482  0.46478375
   0.26814039  0.37555349  0.39590524  0.22463055]
 [-0.46043277  0.39805237  0.37268412  0.22276568  0.49565864 -0.02403753
   0.14180977  0.07271966 -0.33350997 -0.24115478]
 [-0.30192161  0.18580638 -0.12840671 -0.71123187 -0.02576491  0.10946048
   0.47718378 -0.31007677  0.02038784  0.12274863]
 [ 0.26901203  0.09679569 -0.30329614  0.41158977  0.11026846 -0.24897028
   0.62929629 -0.23384344  0.2611964  -0.2525925 ]
 [ 0.1235864   0.12176666  0.0547025   0.12728051  0.27585949 -0.33158646
   0.02475187 -0.12885138 -0.08494957  0.86036434]
 [-0.30114986 -0.2197743  -0.24955475 -0.09226451  0.00559164 -0.35950503
   0.24902454  0.76731762  0.06424171  0.07762742]]
```

But the results didn't seem really relevant and usable)

- **Building an autoencoder** to reduce dimension of my dataset. First i split my data in 2, then i create the autoencoder:

```py
    x_train, x_test = train_test_split(all_features, test_size=0.2)
    
    x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
    x_test = x_test.astype('float32')

    input_size = 41206
    hidden_size = 1280
    code_size = 32
    
    input_data = Input(shape=(input_size,))
    
    hidden_1 = Dense(hidden_size, activation='relu')(input_data)
    code = Dense(code_size, activation='relu')(hidden_1)
    hidden_2 = Dense(hidden_size, activation='relu')(code)
    output_data = Dense(input_size, activation='sigmoid')(hidden_2)
    
    autoencoder = Model(input_data, output_data)
    autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
    autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train, epochs=3)
```

- **Use classical clustering ML algorithms** (knn, dbscan or others)

So i've got 2 major questions:

- what's your level of confidence base on these informations, that it will works ?
- i have trouble creating my autoencoder. When i tried to fit it on my data...

```py
    # train the model
    autoencoder.fit(x_train,
                    x_train,
                    epochs=50,
                    batch_size=256,
                    shuffle=True)
    
    autoencoder.summary()
```

... i have an error:

> TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class
> 'tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor'> to Tensor.
> Contents: SparseTensor(indices=Tensor("DeserializeSparse_1:0",
> shape=(None, 2), dtype=int64), values=Tensor("DeserializeSparse_1:1",
> shape=(None,), dtype=float32), dense_shape=Tensor("stack_1:0",
> shape=(2,), dtype=int64)). Consider casting elements to a supported
> type.

I did a few research on my error, i find this [gitub subject](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25980) that offer a solution by suggesting to create a SparseToDense-Layer. But i have trouble to adapt this solution to my code.

Thank you in advance for everyone taking time to read me ;)

Médéric

Answer (score 0):

I tend to lean towards feature importance experiments for things like this.

Try this code.

```
# Let's load the packages
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.inspection import permutation_importance
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams.update({'figure.figsize': (12.0, 8.0)})
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 14})

# Load the data set and split for training and testing.
boston = load_boston()
X = pd.DataFrame(boston.data, columns=boston.feature_names)
y = boston.target
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=12)

# Fit the Random Forest Regressor with 100 Decision Trees:
rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100)
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# To get the feature importances from the Random Forest model use the feature_importances_ attribute:
rf.feature_importances_

sorted_idx = rf.feature_importances_.argsort()
plt.barh(boston.feature_names[sorted_idx], rf.feature_importances_[sorted_idx])
plt.xlabel("Random Forest Feature Importance")
```

See the link below for more info.

https://towardsdatascience.com/feature-selection-with-pandas-e3690ad8504b

Comment: Thank you for your answer ASH. But after reading this towardsdatascience blogpost, it seems that this solution works only for regression, right ? I did, however, try to use PCA (i edited my question to add this info)

Comment: You are right. I made a mistake. Thanks for correcting me.